# Libcurl C++ - How do I post form data for this specific form?

Tags: html, c++, forms, libcurl, fieldset

How do I post and then submit form data for the following form using libcurl and C++?

```
<form id="loginContainer" class="controllerContainer" action="/j_spring_security_check" method="post">

<h2>Login</h2>
<hr>
<fieldset>

    <div class="field">
        <input class="standard" name="j_username" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" size="25" placeholder="Enter Username">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <input class="standard" name="j_password" type="password" value="" size="25" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Enter Password (case-sensitive)">
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <button class="login" type="submit"></button>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

I have tried several examples from the curl website but none of them worked for me.

EDIT: Here is the function I made to login

```
void loginToWebsite(std::string url, std::string userAgent, std::string username, std::string password)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, userAgent.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ("j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password).c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    }
```

Comment: Please show what you have actually tried, so we can explain what you did wrong with it. libcurl examples work when used correctly, so you must not have used them correctly. But we can't see the code you used.

Comment: Ok I added the code. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are leaking the `curl` object. You need to call [`curl_easy_cleanup()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_cleanup.html) when you are done using it.

But, more importantly, you are using [`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html) incorrectly. You are passing it a `char*` pointer to a temporary `std::string` that goes out of scope immediately, leaving curl with a dangling pointer to invalid memory by the time `curl_easy_perform()` is called. You need to either

- use a local `std::string` variable
- use [`CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_COPYPOSTFIELDS.html).

You also need to url-encode the form parameters that you post. You can use [`curl_easy_escape()`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html) for that.

With that said, try something more like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void loginToWebsite(const std::string &url, const std::string &userAgent, const std::string &username, const std::string &password)
{
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, userAgent.c_str());
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

        std::ostringstream oss;

        oss << "j_username=";
        char *encoded = curl_easy_escape(curl, username.c_str(), username.length());
        if (encoded)
        {
            oss << encoded;
            curl_free(encoded);
        }

        oss << "&j_password=";
        encoded = curl_easy_escape(curl, password.c_str(), password.length());
        if (encoded)
        {
            oss << encoded;
            curl_free(encoded);
        }

        std::string postdata = oss.str();    
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postdata.c_str());

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");

        CURLcode res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        // use res as needed...

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to let you know I had the same issue and it was the temporary string. I had a `std::stringstream` and `ss.str().c_str()` is not valid to pass in